# Embedly CDN Url is asking for captcha

Tags: embedly

I am using embedly for one of my project. Following is the CDN URL which I used:

http://cdn.embed.ly/jquery.embedly-3.1.1.min.js

It was working earlier but now the URL is asking for captcha first.

I am not able to access the URL directly. So getting jquery error.

How can I solve this issue? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We've turned off Cloudflare security for the domain. Please let me know if you still experience issues.

Comment: Thanks a alot! I hope you will not add the security captcha in future again. And If you do please let us know the alternative. So that our site doesn't stop working :)